# How to get AffectedRows and Row at the same time?

Tags: go

This is my query:

```
query="INSERT INTO account(address,owner_id,deleted,block_del,ts_created,block_created) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING account_id";
```

After executing the query I want to know both things: `affected rows` + the `account_id` serial field that has been incremented during `INSERT`.

How can I do it?

If I use `db.Exec()` I will only get affected rows:

```
result,err := db.Exec(query, addr_str, owner_id, deleted, block_del, timestamp, block_num);
affected_rows,err:=result.RowsAffected()
```

If I use `db.QueryRow()` I can get the `account_id` but I will not be able to get AffectedRows:

```
row:=db.QueryRow(query,addr_str,owner_id,deleted,block_del,timestamp,block_num);
account_id,err:=row.Scan(&account_id)
```

But how to get both of them  ??? Is there any function what will return `db.Row` and `db.Result` at the same time ?

Comment: You're inserting one row, hence the affected row should be 1 if the insert succeded, or do you expect it to return something else?

Comment: yes, the returned rows should be 1, and the idea to get AffectedRows is to prove that the insert was successful

Comment: If the insert was unsuccessful then scanning the account_id through row will return an error.

Comment: well, somehow, the insert fails but doesn't returns an error, so I want to get AffectedRows to double check

Comment: How do you know it failed if you're not getting an error? What's the value `account_id` after you call `Scan`?

Comment: Just to be clear I don't think what you look for is possible, retrieving rows and affected rows in one go, so I believe you'll have to find another solution for your problem.

Comment: I know it fails because it doesn't insert the record, I test it in `psql` console

Comment: If `Scan` doesn't return an error what's the value of `account_id`?

Comment: @mkopriva, I found a bug in the code, the INSERT statement was being skipped, that's why the record it wasn't inserted.  But anyway, it would be nice to have rows affected and the autoincremented filed both returned by the driver

Comment: The `sql.Result` interface has the method called `LastInsertId()`, I think you missed it.